# stdio.h or unistd.h, which is faster for file creation/writing/reading?

Tags: c, file-io, stdio, unistd.h

Which header functions are faster for creating, editing and reading many small files? About thousands of files of about 100 bytes each. I'm using C on Windows, Devcpp.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 100 bytes? It Makes No Difference.

Comment: Although it does not matter for a 100 bytes of file but for a big file do check that if the buffering is enabled.  The higher level functions can have buffering enabled which can reduce the amount of physical I/O, meaning it can reduce the actual number of read()/write() calls that get made

Comment: it could depend on the quality of the implementation, if in doubt -- run some measurements

Answer (score 4):

`stdio.h` is the header for stream/buffered I/O(like `fprintf()`).

`unistd.h` is the header for the `POSIX` API(like `read()`).

The choice to use buffered/non-buffered I/O depends on what the application is doing.

it's generally better to use the C standard library functions in `stdio.h` where you can (i.e. for file I/O) and then use the POSIX standard functions in `unistd.h` etc. when you need to do I/O on file descriptors for sockets and such.

Comment: You can actually use `fdopen()` to create a `FILE*` from a file descriptor (`int`).  Then you can use sockets with `stdio.h`.